# How to Open Menu from Activity w/o toolbar or menu button

Tags: android, android-studio, menu

I want to open the menu, the problem is my game uses full screen so there is no toolbar, no room for a FAB and no menu button. I have tried to use

```
openOptionsMenu();
```

in an onClickListener from a button on the screen but it does nothing. If you have any suggestions please reply here.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found was to use the PopupMenu, see the example and comments below.

```
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener; 

public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.new_game_button:
            //start new game
            break;

        case R.id.menu_button:
            /** Instantiating PopupMenu class */
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getBaseContext(), view);
            /** Adding menu items to the popumenu */
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game_menu, popup.getMenu());
            /** Defining menu item click listener for the popup menu */
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {

                        case R.id.menu_more_apps:
                            //do something
                            return true;

                        case R.id.menu_about:
                            // do something
                            return true;

                        case R.id.menu_like_us:
                            //do something
                            return true;
            break;
```